# :4200//assets/config.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, http-status-code-404, config.json

Using VS code angular 14

Project was updated from angular 8

ng build and ng serve works fine.

But http://localhost:4200/ give this error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
:4200//assets/config.json:1

And I stuck here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R86G.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfhaA.png)

Comment: Hi, maybe because your assets url have two // ? if you enter in your browser http://localhost:4200/assets/config.json it shows something?

Comment: was the code throwing this error prior to the angular upgrade ? what changes (roughly) do you remember making after the most recent commit that was not throwing this error ?

Comment: you are right, removing one backslash reach the file, but why is there 2 backslash, can't find anywhere in the project files.  I had baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/', in file protractor.conf.js, I removed the last backslash. I rebuild and but still the UI is looking for  :4200//assets/config.json

Comment: The code has not change since angular was upgraded.

Comment: In the file configuration.service.ts

there is this

Comment: private get configurationUrl(): string {
const path = (environment.configurationPath.startsWith('/') ? '' : '/') + environment.configurationPath;
        const baseUrl = this.window.document.baseURI;

        return `${baseUrl}${path}`;
    }

Comment: I changed the first line because it is adding a backslash for I don’t know what reason.

private get configurationUrl(): string {
        const path =  environment.configurationPath;
        const baseUrl = this.window.document.baseURI;

        return `${baseUrl}${path}`;
}

And this solve the issue.

So thank you all for your help, it made me think to look for this double backslash.

Answer (score 0):

In the file `configuration.service.ts` there is this

```
private get configurationUrl(): string { 
const path = (environment.configurationPath.startsWith('/') ? '' : '/') + environment.configurationPath; const baseUrl = this.window.document.baseURI; return ${baseUrl}${path}; 
}
```

I changed the first line because it is adding a backslash for I don’t know what reason.

```
private get configurationUrl(): string { 
const path = environment.configurationPath; const baseUrl = this.window.document.baseURI; return ${baseUrl}${path}; 
}
```

And this solve the issue. So thank you all for your help, it made me think to look for this double backslash